# C99 can type modifiers appear to the right of the type

Tags: language-lawyer, c99

I like putting type qualifiers to the right of the type especially for pointer declarations because it makes reading the declaration using the [right-left rule](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ericko/rt_lt.rule.html) easier.
E.g.

```
uint8_t volatile * const p_foo; // p_foo is a const pointer to a volatile uint8_t
```

Putting type qualifiers to the right of the type is legal in C99. But what about type modifiers like `signed` and `long`?

E.g.

```
`int signed const * const p_bar; // is it legal in C99 to put 'signed' to the right of 'int'?`
```

FWIW `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` doesn't make any noise about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In section 6.7.2, Paragraph 2 of [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=111)

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and  in  the  specifier-qualifier  list  in  each  struct  declaration  and  type  name.Each  list  of type  specifiers  shall  be  one  of  the  following  sets  (delimited  by  commas,  when  there  is more  than  one  set  on  a  line);  the  type  specifiers  may  occur  in  any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

Since `int`, `char`, etc, are themselves specifiers then I think the answer is "yes, it is legal to reverse the order of `signed int` to `int signed`".